# iPhone - iOS Shortcuts app - Shortcut for skip recurring alarms

Tags: ios, iphone, shortcut, sirishortcuts, ios16

I have few different recurring alarm setups for different weeks of month. I set them manually every Sunday. But sometimes I wake up before alarm time, want to skip recurring alarms for that day. Stupid but it's impossible in ios. Everytime you have to turn off all alarms you have, wait for alarms time to pass, then remember that you've turned it off and turn on again.

It becomes so hard especially when you're just woke up. Since I couldn't find any solution, I've tried to create a shortcut.

-You can only skip recurring alarm on sleep mode but I have multiple alarms and don't wanna use sleep mode so that's not an option-

This is my shortcut:

[shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN1Ri.jpg)

It's working, but, there are few things I couldn't solve since I'm not very familiar with ios shortcuts app.

1- If I run it on shortcuts app, it works. But if I quit shortcuts app by swiping up on control center, it stoppes running. And I'm worry that I may forgot not to quit the app while it's waiting on the background for 1 hour to reactivate alarms.

2- If I put the shortcut on home screen as an app, a notification pops up, and you can't swipe it up until the shortcut is done. Which takes 1 hour. I don't know how to solve this issue, it's kinda bummer trying to find shortcuts app everytime while you're half asleep.

[notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVJ3Q.jpg)

3- If I ask siri to run the shortcut, same as problem number 2, siri waits on screen until shortcut finishes. So that's even worse because siri makes phone unusable while on screen.

So I don't know maybe if there's an option for it in shortcuts or a workaround, it would be nice to have.

I'm using iphone 13, ios 16.0.2

PS: Apple, FIX THIS.

Answer (score 0):

dont know if youve found a solution to this already. First thing i can think of is breaking that shortcut into two shortcuts. the first to cancel whichever alarms you want. the second would be to reenable those alarms. You could actually setup a personal automation to trigger after the setpoints of the group of alarms to turn them back on. Or you can have them turned back on automatically through personal automation when your phone switches to "sleep" focus, if you have that setup.

My issue at the moment is i want to use shortcuts to both create and delete( or atleast edit the alarm time) when i stop it after it goes off. but even though shortcuts can create them, and Siri can delete them if asked, apparently shortcuts cant delete or modify alarms. it can only bring you to the edit screen for the selected alarm which is not the point of automation.

Comment: Actually, I stopped thinking on it and I'm manually turning on and off alarms. It doesn't worth to try for me because in every scenario I've tried, something was working in a way I didn't want. Apple should fix this asap.